# how to parse users facebook friend list using java?

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, servlets

I am making a facebook app .I am able to fetch a user's friend list using the graph api.The friend list is returned in the form of JSON.How to parse it is using java?I have the json simple library but i am having trouble using it.

Comment: Can you post your code? What have you tried so far, and what's the trouble you are facing?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples i tried to use the code in example 1.But it gives a ClassCastException..it showsorg.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
String response = .....

JSONArray arr = (JSONArray)JSONValue.parse(response);
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(response);
```

You should be able to know if the returned response is an array or object based on what you asked for.

---

## Edit

In the case you get a json object which contains an array:

```
String response = .....

JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(response);

if (obj.containsKey("xxxx")) {
    JSONArray arr = (JSONArray)obj.get("xxxx");
}
```

The JSONObject supports java.util.Map interface and JSONArray the supports java.util.List interface.

Comment: The  friends list  is very long.Should i keep iterating within a loop.In some cases there are objects within objects as well?How do i cope with it?

Comment: The first line of your code throws an exception.. org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

Comment: It's not both lines, it's the first or the second, depending on what you're asking from the graph api. If you asking for an array then use the 1st, otherwise use the 2nd.

Comment: i have an object and that object contains an array

Answer (score 1):

**edit: This is for the full JSON library not the org.json simple library. Please look at Nitzan's answer for the org.json simple library**

You would need to get a value from the `JSONObject`. For example lets say your `JSONObject` is called jObj:

`jObj.getString("parameter_name");`

If you are given a JSONArray, you would need to get the correct JSONObject from the JSONArray by doing this:

`JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(0);`

replace 0 with the `JSONObject` you would like to retrieve

Comment: I have a string containing JSON that i fetched from the graph api url.How to convert that into JSON Object?

Comment: I believe you can do `JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(resultString)` Then retrieve the correct parameter from my answer above.

Comment: There is no such constructor for JSONObject class

Comment: Hmm, i just tried it out and it seems to be compiling fine for me. Did you import `org.json.JSONObject`?

Comment: i have the org.json simple library

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, didn't completely read your question then. In that case the answer from Nitzan should work.

Comment: Again there is no such method as getJsonObject in the json simple library

Comment: Dont worry i figured it out..Thanks for devoting your time